# Converting from 360 degree vr to rectangular

Tags: virtual-reality, conversion, video

What I am interested in doing is taking a 360 degree stereo video (Oculus Rift etc), and a description of how the viewing direction changes with time (rather than reading from gyroscopes) and then rendering that to a simple side by side rectangular video (so that you can stick the result on a smartphone and view it with the inbuilt video viewer).

This will naturally involve something like sphere mapping the source, and rendering the result, as the smartphone apps do. I am interested in doing this transformation offline. Is there software around that already does this? Or what are the most suitable libraries to use if I want to program it myself?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "360 degree stereo video"? You can create a stereo image by taking two images from  different positions (approximating one from each eye). However, if you take two 360 degree images then the stereo effect will be strongest in the directions perpendicular to the offset between the images, and zero in the directions parallel to the offset. To get a stereo effect in all directions I would expect two images in each of a wide variety of directions to be necessary. Answering your question will require knowing more about the input that is provided.

Comment: In the sense of what Kolor Eyes uses. You have a video, e.g. 1920x1080, split into two halves (side by side), each half (960x1080) then needs to be mapped onto a sphere and then you render the viewpoint of a viewer at the centre of that sphere looking out in a particular direction.

Comment: Kolor Eyes appears to provide 360 degree video, but not in stereo. Are you looking to make your 360 degree stereo video by combining two 360 degree videos from two similar viewpoints, or by combining a large number of 360 degree videos from many similar viewpoints?

Comment: You mention rendering in your comment. Are you working with recorded real world video here, or a rendered artificial scene?

Comment: Note that requests for software recommendations and off site resources are off topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I recommend editing to remove the request for existing software or libraries, keeping just the request for how to program this yourself, in order to avoid the question being closed.